# MVVM WPF databound checkbox won't firing events to the ViewModel for Checked and Unchecked states

Tags: wpf, mvvm, checkbox

I have a databound `CheckBox` inside a `DataGrid`, using WPF and MVVM;

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="80" Header="Enabled">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,  Mode=TwoWay}" Name="theCheckbox" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This works fine and the `CheckBox` is being checked when `IsEnabled` is set.  `IsEnabled` is a property in my collection of objects which I have bound to the `DataGrid`.  What I want to do is to be able to validate if a specific rows `CheckBox` within the `DataGrid` should be allowed to be checked when the user selects it and if not remove their check and display a warning message something like "Row 1 cannot be checked without rows 5 and 9 being checked".  I found out how to do this using code behind using the `Checked` and `Unchecked` properties of the `CheckBox`, but I am using MVVM and therefore want to handle things in the `ViewModel` associated with the View the `DataGrid` and `CheckBox` are in.  How do I do this?  I need a way of passing the Id field of the `DataRow` through too in order to identify which row I am working on, for arguments sake lets say the Id field is called `BorderId`.

Answer (score 1):

Implement [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) on your objects, which is WPF's default interface for validation, and setup your validation code to validate if the checkbox can be checked or not

This is actually a bit trickier than normal because you are validating a property on your data item using data that doesn't exist on the data item, which means you need to provide some way of attaching unrelated validation to your object at run time.

The solution I usually use is to expose a ValidationDelegate from my object, which other objects can use to attach additional validation to the object. The code for it is posted [on my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/01/22/validating-business-rules-in-mvvm/), and it allows you to attach validation to your object like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    // Keeping this generic to reduce code here, but it
    // should be a full property with PropertyChange notification
    public ObservableCollection<SomeObject> SomeCollection { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        SomeCollection = LoadDataGridObjects();

        // Add the validation delegate to each object
        foreach(var item in SomeCollection)
            item.AddValidationDelegate(ValidateObject);
    }

    // Validation Delegate to verify the right checkboxes are checked
    private string ValidateObject(object sender, string propertyName)
    {
        if (propertyName == "IsChecked")
        {
            var item = (SomeObject)sender;
            if (item.Id == 1
                && !SomeCollection.First(p => p.Id == 5).IsChecked
                && !SomeCollection.First(p => p.Id == 9).IsChecked)
            {
                return "Row 1 cannot be checked without rows 5 and 9 being checked";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you add to the PropertyChanged event handler of each item in your list? Something like this:

```
foreach (Object x in List)
{
    x.PropertyChanged += OnItemChanged;
}
```

Then in the change listener you can do whatever you like with the sender object including changing the IsEnabled property.

```
void OnItemChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // change sender object properties or set bound label text here
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand what it is you're trying to point out. Do you mean the OnPropertyChange event would be fired whenever someone selected a checkbox?  If so this may work but I wanted a more direct approach instead of iterating over what could be thousands of rows in the collection to check what has been updated.  In the ViewModel I really need a switch statement using the BorderId passed back then I can write validation code to check if required checkboxes in other rows have been selected.

Comment: This is not a very good way of doing this, as it still allows the CheckBox to get selected, then throws an error and unchecks the property again. It also runs the risk of getting stuck in a loop if the property is not valid when both checked and unchecked. In addition, you shouldn't need to run code to update your UI objects from your ViewModel in MVVM :)

Comment: Good point about the loop problem Rachel. Your solution is definitely more elegant. Just to clarify to the OP, the foreach loop would only be run once, when setting up the list. The OnItemChanged code would be fired as a given item was changed, passing that object as the sender variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you have a checkbox and you want to control if it can be checked or not. Instead of letting the user check it at all times and push back an error message if you don't want to allow it, make your checkbox inactive in the first place if you don't want the user to check it.

To do this through your ViewModel (which is of course your DataContext), you need to bind the Checkbox's "Command" to a custom command in your ViewModel.

A [WPF Command](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238657/How-to-use-Commands-in-WPF) will provide the following functionality:

- Automatically enable/disable a control based on custom logic
- Handles the "action" event of your control (on a button of checkbox, it would be "click").